# Launchpad vs Development kit

Tags: development-tools

Whats the difference between a Launchpad and a Development Kit? Many launchpads like the TI's Stellaris/Hercules launchpads even support In circuit debugging capabilities via USB. This eliminates the need of purchasing a JTAG debugger.

Comment: Very often, cost. Some Development Kits are still hundreds of $$$ because they are often aimed at corporate customers not students or hobbyists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"LaunchPad" is the name given to TI's development kits that support expansion via "BoosterPacks". So in short, practically nothing.

Comment: I agree. It's all about how the company names their product.